# How to do a combined boolean operation in neptune using gremlin and python?

Tags: python, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am trying to do a query where I have multiple boolean operations to be done but can't figure out how to do it.

The query is something like `(A and B) or (C and D)`

I first tried

```
g.V()\
.has("attra", P.lte(20))\
.has("attrb", P.gte(10))\
.or_()\
.has("attrc", P.lte(20))\
.has("attrd", P.gte(10))
```

but it turns out anything after the `or_()` in the query is `or`ed and that is not what I want. Because I have other complex boolean logic down the line as well.

and I also tried

```
g.V()\
.or_(
  has("attra", P.lte(20)).and().has("attrb", P.gte(10)),
  has("attrc", P.lte(20)).and().has("attrd", P.gte(10))
)
```

but it says that `has` is not defined. Is this how you do it? Where is this has even defined?

Help would be really appreciated

EDIT: I have the following imports in my file

```
from __future__ import print_function
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __ as AnonymousTraversal
```

Answer (score 1):

I found where the `has` is defined.

It can be found here

```
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __ as AnonymousTraversal
```

so we just do

```
has = AnonymousTraversal.has
```

and query like this

```
g.V()\
.or_(
  has("attra", P.lte(20)).and().has("attrb", P.gte(10)),
  has("attrc", P.lte(20)).and().has("attrd", P.gte(10))
)
```

Comment: Glad you got it working. There are a few ways you can handle the imports with Gremlin Python. One way is to add things to globals as statics. Another way is to just prefix any anonymous traversal with __. That way you will not have to explicitly assign each member of the AnonymousTraversal class (there are a lot of them).

Comment: thanks for the advice. There actually are a lot of them :D I realized it as well after working with it for a while. And I really like the prefixing idea as well. Thank you again